# how to verify that entry A with version X is newer than entry A with version X-1 in pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
document id   document version   version date
101            1                  2020-01-01
101            2                  2020-01-02
102            1                  2020-01-01
103            1                  2019-05-02
101            3                  2019-12-03
102            2                  2020-01-02
```

I can't figure out how to identify rows that have newer document version with the version date before or equal the date of the previous version.

So in this example, I want to identify row 5 with document 101, version 3 and date 2019-12-03 which is before the date of the version 2 of this document.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried at @Allen option and wasnt quite getting desired outcome.

Try sort by `document id` and `document version`, [dfgroupby.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) and filter negative values

```
df1=df.sort_values(['document id', 'document version'])
df1['document date ']=pd.to_datetime(df1['document date '])
df1[df1.groupby('document id')['document date '].apply(lambda x: x.diff(1)).astype('timedelta64[D]')<0]
```

Outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use apply:

```
(
    df.apply(lambda x: ((df['document id']==x['document id']) & 
                        (df['document version']<x['document version']) &
                        (df['version date']>x['version date'])).any(), axis=1)
    .pipe(lambda x: df.loc[x])
)

    document id document version    version date
4   101         3                   2019-12-03
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It works on an example df but was taking too much time on my original df ~(800k, 20) - I had to cancel execution after several minutes.